# The node to be inserted is from a different document context

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am getting this error in my function below.

```
Public Function GetXmlEnvironment(ByVal xmlTree As XmlNode, ByVal objUser As XTUser, ByVal objModule As XTModuleInfo, ByVal objProject As XTProject, ByVal objPage As IXTPage) As XmlNode

    Dim objXml As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
    Dim xmlEnvironment As XmlElement

    xmlEnvironment = objXml.CreateElement("Environment")
    If (xmlTree.HasChildNodes()) Then
        xmlTree.FirstChild.AppendChild(xmlEnvironment) ' Error occurs here
    End If
' ...
End Function
```

Do I need to convert the XmlElement into an XmlNode?

Comment: Use the OwnerDocument of xmlTree.FirstChild to create a new element, not a brand new XmlDocument.

Comment: @Parfait , the title is the error.

Comment: I was going to say to `import` the node before appending it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public Function GetXmlEnvironment(ByVal xmlTree As XmlNode, ByVal objUser As XTUser, ByVal objModule As XTModuleInfo, ByVal objProject As XTProject, ByVal objPage As IXTPage) As XmlNode
  Dim objXml As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
  Dim xmlEnvironment As XmlElement
  xmlEnvironment = objXml.CreateElement("Environment")
  If (xmlTree.HasChildNodes()) Then
    xmlTree.FirstChild.AppendChild(xmlTree.OwnerDocument.ImportNode(xmlEnvironment, True))
  End If
  '...'
End Function
```